# How to test for temperature differences between years and sites?

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a dataset with monthly temperatures for 4 different years and I would like to test if they are significantly different between the years. As I collected the data for different sites I wondered if there were some possibility to perform the calculation at once or if I have to repeat it for each site. I am using the statistical software R.

Alternatively, can you indicate me some way to plot this?

My data look like this (I have some missing values):

Code:

```
> head(MeanTemp)
  Site Year    Month     Temp
1    1 2008  January       NA
2    1 2008 February       NA
3    1 2008   March        NA
4    1 2008    April       NA
5    1 2008      May 16.22594
6    1 2008     June 18.53764
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I very much doubt that the differences will be statistically significant, as there is a lot of inter-annual variability in temperatures (especially for station level data), so you will need large deviations for a statistically significant difference from a small sample of measurements.  Essentially the [statistical power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) of the test is likely to be so low that the test is not useful.

Can you give some explanation of the purpose of the study?  What hypothesis are you investigating?

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact the purpose is not to show that it is statistically different. I collected insects during three Summers in several study sites and I would like to see if there abundance depends on temperature. Now why I want to know if temperatures are different between years is because if there is a good correlation in temperature between years, I can use the temperature data of any year as input in my insect abundance model. If temperatures are not correlated I have to consider them as additional factors in difference in insect abundance between the years. Not sure if I'm clear.

Comment: Sounds interesting. If you want to establish that there is no significant difference, then the power of the test becomes more important, as it is the frequency with whch the test will reject the null when it is false.  If you don't have very much data then it is likely that you will not be able to reject the null not becuase there is evidence that it is false, but becuase there isn't enough evidence (data) to argue convincingly either. I think I would include it if there were good biological reasons why it should be relevant regardless of the statistics.  HTH

Comment: Thank you very much. I just still have trouble how to get this statistical power. If you can help me a little bit further, but maybe I am asking too much

Comment: Statistical power is rather difficult to compute (much more so than significance), which I suspect is why it tends to get neglected.  However in this case, I think that it is safe to assume that the statistical power will be pretty low because there is so little data.  I would instead be guided by biological/meteorological expert knowledge.